# Is there a way to capture debug output from a VMware instance?

Tags: debugging, vmware, remote-debugging

We are running a VM on a VMware workstation 7. We are trying to capture debug output (written using OutputDebugString) that happened while booting (but not from the kernel). Is there a way to connect DebugView to a VM?

Comment: Can you attach a virtual serial cable to a virtual serial port in the VM?

Comment: @Gabe, in a virtual world, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Log Boot feature of DbgView on the virtual computer itself. Just select Capture - Log Boot and reboot virtual computer. After it restarts, open DbgView and see all boot trace messages.

If you want to connect to another (virtual or real) computer and see its trace, both from kernel and user mode, you need Windows Debugging Tools (WinDbg), and not DbgView. Read this article: http://www.catch22.net/tuts/vmware

Comment: For some reason, LogBoot can only capture kernel info. My information comes from a user service / process.